# Removing especial characters from a string list in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, data-structures, replace

I have two lists; the first a string list with names (`name_list`) in it and a second list with especial characters (`char_list`). What I'm looking for to do is to remove all the especial characters that are found in any placement of each letter in each name from the `name_list`.

***Psdt.** I know that there are other ways to do so (like using reg) but in this case I'm attempting to do it without using such especial functions/libraries, just .replace() at much like I've been trying shown below:*

Say this is my full especial characters list:

```
char_list = ['%',']','(','/','&','?','¨','+']
```

Those characters above are the ones that I'm looking for to replace in the `name_list`, say these are the names:

```
name_list = ['LAURE]N', 'NIC%HOL/AS', 'nichol?as', '(Vic(t¨oria', 'H+AROLD']
```

And this is my attempt using loops and conditionals but I still haven't got it quite right:

```
for index, value in enumerate(name_list):
 
  if char_list[index + 1] in value:
    name_list[index + 1].lower().replace(char_list[index + 1], "")
  
  print(set(name_list))
```

*I'm printing `set(name_list)` and including `.lower()` because besides removing/replacing the chars I'm also trying to retrieve the unique names from the `name_list`*

This is of course giving me an error because I haven't figured out yet so any help to do it properly this way or very close without other libraries is very well received! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to do the `in` check.  Just do the replaces.

```
char_list = '%](/&?¨+'
name_list = ['LAURE]N', 'NIC%HOL/AS', 'nichol?as', '(Vic(t¨oria', 'H+AROLD']
new_list = []
for n in name_list:
    for c in char_list:
        n = n.replace(c,'')
    new_list.append(n)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! May I ask you, do you know how can I remove the comma (included in the `char_list` too) if it's within a string without getting removed the comma as a separator of each name in the `name_list`?

Comment: Just to clarify, it worked really well in the example I posted however, in what I'm working on, is considering the comma separator and is also removing it from the list besides the commas in the strings!